# How to create service Account in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to get 7 pace timesheet details along with Azure DevOps work details programmatically using PAT token. I want to use a service account instead of a user account.
Can you please guide me to create a service account?

1. This service account should have 7 pace applications along with
   Azure DevOps access.
2. The service account MFA should be disabled.
   So that it can be used in Azure Runbook.

Answer (score 0):

You must choose a new account that is either a system account or a member of a workgroup or domain that is trusted by every computer in this deployment of Azure DevOps Server.

Then you can have a service account in the two ways :

**Use the administration console to change the service account**

1. Open the administration console for Azure DevOps on the server that hosts the application tier.
2. In the console, expand the server name and select Application Tier.
3. In the **Application Tier** pane, select **Change Account**.
   The **Update Service Account** window opens.
4. Perform one of the following steps:

- To use a system account, select Use a system account, and then select a system account from the drop-down list - If your server is a member of an Active Directory domain, the default choice for the system account to use is Network Service. If your server is a member of a workgroup, the default choice is Local Service. Depending on the details of your deployment, the default choice may be the only available choice.
- To use a domain or workgroup account, select **Use a user account**, enter the name of the account in **Account Name**, and then enter the password for that account in **Password**.

**Use the TFSConfig utility to change the service account**

1. On the application-tier server, open a Command Prompt window and change directories to the directory that contains the **TFSConfig** utility. By default, this utility is located in `Drive:\Program Files\TFS 12.0\Tools`.
2. At the command line, enter `TFSConfig Accounts /change /accountType:ApplicationTier /account:AccountName /password:NewPassword`, and then press **ENTER**.